# What does structure matrix do

Tags: image-processing

can anybody explain to me what does structure matrix exactly do in image processing? What happens to the pixels?

By structure matrix I mean:

$$S_w[p] = \begin{pmatrix} \sum_{r}w(r)[I_x(p-r)]^2 & \sum_{r}w(r)[I_x(p-r) I_y(p-r)]  \\ \sum_{r}w(r)[I_x(p-r) I_y(p-r)] & \sum_{r}w(r)[I_y(p-r)]^2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Could you please tell us what you do consider to be a structure matrix, and where you found the reference?

Comment: I have added the definition of that to my question and it is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_tensor)

Comment: OK, I know it under the names: *structure tensor* or *second-order matrix*

Answer (score 2):

At each pixel $p$, this $2\times 2$ matrix summarizes the local behavior  of the image (structure) inside a neighborhood of pixel $p$ (a neighborhood weighted by function $w$.

From this matrix, different quantities can be computed, that provide interesting attributes for image analysis. Structure tensors, or second-order matrices, have been used for image segmentation, especially with geodesic or level-set methods, as they can provide insights to image textures or orientations.